# How to run "winrm quickconfig" on all LAN computers remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to start doing my remote LAN work using powershell, but it seems I need to run `winrm quickconfig` on all LAN computers before I can remotely connect to them.

How can I run that command on all computers without having to manually go to each computer to run it?

Comment: Group Policy is the way.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/03/17/three-ways-to-configure-winrm-listeners.aspx

Comment: @Zoredache Why is this a comment and not an answer? I feel this is the proper answer to the question.

Comment: @JasonTaylor because on stackexchange link-only answers are generally discouraged.  (links break, they aren't very useful google wise). I was being too lazy at the time to actually create an answer that described the process of using group policies to accomplish this.  I was hoping someone else would take the time to follow the link and generate a useful answer. If you want some free rep you could go create an answer with a quick and dirt summary of what is on that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into using PSTools (specifically, PSExec) to run it. I believe you can specify a text file with computer names in it for PSExec to run through, and you can use PSexec to do a WinRM quickconfig.

Answer (score 3):

```
psexec \\PCNAMEHERE -s winrm.cmd quickconfig -q
```

or

```
psexec \\* -s winrm.cmd quickconfig -q
```

that "should" hit ever online pc on the network, or, export a list of PC names from AD or SCCM, then save the list as a text file and run this..

```
psexec @c:\temp\allpcs.txt -s winrm.cmd quickconfig -q
```

Answer (score 0):

The only I can think of is to embed it into a login script.  Even then you'd have to elevate the user rights so it can make the changes.  The affected keys and services require administrator rights.